# Всплывающее окно, с заранее заданными полями и кнопками

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде контекстного меню или диалога. Должно всплывать окно, поверх активити с заранее заданными полями и кнопками. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать?.

Выражусь точней, окно должно всплывать с текстовыми полями, несколькими кнопками, а закрываться только по одной кнопке. И желательно, чтобы оно было сделано заранее в xml-разметке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать кастомный диалог с вашей разметкой.

Пусть оповещает вызывающую его Activity о результатах работы (можно добавить, например, интерфейс)

Comment: а можно подробней как такое сделать?

Comment: допустим у вас есть разметка в которой есть 2 едита и 1 кнопка (допустим custom_dialog.xml)

Создаете класс наследующийся от Dialog (пусть будет CustomDialog extends Dialog).
В методе onCreate(...) выполняете setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

Также в этом классе описываете интерфейс OnButtonClickListener с методом buttonClicked(String firstEditText, String secondEditText);

Comment: И в качестве одного из параметров конструктора должен быть слушатель OnButtonClickListener listener (будет передаваться, например, Activity)

В случае события нажатия на кнопку выполняете listener.buttonClicked(editText1.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString()); и закрываете диалог (this.dismiss())

В нужном Activity реализуете данный интерфейс (CustomDialog.OnButtonClickListener и передаете как параметр в конструктор вашего диалога)

Сорри, если сумбурно описал. Надеюсь вы поймете

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/contextmenu.php

Comment: поэтому это не совсем то

Контекстное меню практически содержит только выбор действий (по сути ничем не отличается от обычного меню)

EditText туда не запихаешь